# Did Voldemort Have a Dark Mark?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Voldemort bestowed the Dark Mark on only those in his inner circle.

> [Fenrir Greyback] might be allowed to wear Death Eater robes when they wanted to use him, but only Voldemort’s inner circle were branded with the Dark Mark: Greyback had not been granted this highest honour.
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 368 - Bloomsbury - chapter 23, *Malfoy Manor*</sub>

But did Voldemort himself have a Dark Mark? He puts his wand to Wormtail's Dark Mark to summon the Death Eaters in *Goblet of Fire*, which suggests he does *not* have a Dark Mark. On the other hand, he stated in *Goblet of Fire* that he and his Death Eaters were reunited under the Dark Mark when Voldemort was returned to his body.

> ‘Welcome, Death Eaters,’ said Voldemort quietly. ‘Thirteen years ... thirteen years since last we met. Yet you answer my call as though it was yesterday ... we are still united under the Dark Mark, then! *Or are we*?’ [dramatic gopher]
>   <sub>*Goblet of Fire* - page 561 - Bloomsbury - chapter 33, *The Death Eaters*</sub>

This could be referring to the Dark Mark that comes from Morsmordre (the Dark Mark in the sky), although nobody casts Morsmordre at the graveyard the night Voldemort is resurrected. Further, Voldemort had to have a way of summoning the Death Eaters to him when he is alone. How would he do this without a Dark Mark? **Did Voldemort have a Dark Mark? If not, how does he summon his Death Eaters when alone?** I'm looking for a canon-based answer, meaning no Wikis/Wikias -- only the books, Pottermore, or information from J.K. Rowling.

Comment: Knowing Voldemort, I'd imagine not, but nothing to back it up.

Comment: The Death Eaters can use their Marks to summon Voldemort, so he either has a Mark himself or, as the creator of the spell, has an affinity with them that doesn't require him to have one. That seems contrary to the fact that he (always?) uses a Death Eaters Mark to summon the Death Eaters to him. Purely speculation, though.

Comment: I imagine by not having one, Voldemort is able to assert some level of control and power over his followers. By being "disconnected" he is then able  lower their status in relation to himself, and therefore be a leader among them.

Comment: Are you asking about his first body or his second one?

Comment: @b_jonas - Your choice.

Comment: When Voldemort uses Wormtail's dark Mark, his body had just been regenerated, and it is only natural to assume that he could not have had the Dark Mark _then_. But he could have cast the required charm on his  arm later on. Is there any instance in the books, of his using someone else's Mark after this, or before his first disappearance?

Comment: i wonder who the first was to have a dark mark? avery or the carrows or bellatrix even?

Comment: @BP_Phoenix -  I would think it likely the first Death Eaters to receive Dark Marks may have been Nott, Rosier, Mulciber, and Dolohov. In *Half-Blood Prince*, in the chapter called *Lord Voldemort's Request*, Dumbledore names these four as (at least some of) the first Death Eaters, as they were the ones traveling with Voldemort to Hogsmeade when Voldemort met with Dumbledore to ask for the DADA teaching position. I believe Mulciber, Nott, and Dolohove went to Azkaban rather than betray Voldemort. Rosier died fighting for Voldemort's ideals, so they probably would have been in the inner circle.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin and would back it up with this Dumbledore quote from Half Blood Prince Chp 13- The Secret Riddle: `Firstly, I hope you noticed Riddle’s reaction when I mentioned that another shared his first name, 'Tom'? [...] There he showed his contempt for anything that tied him to other people, anything that made him ordinary.`. Voldemort would never brand himself with the mark of his servants, he's better than all of them.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> 'You know what these remind me of?'
>   'No, what's that?'
>   'The Death Eaters' scars. Voldemort touches one of them, and all their scars burn, and they know they've got to join him.'
>   
>   <sub>*Order Of The Pheonix* - page 353 - Bloomsbury - chapter 19, *The Lion and The Serpent*</sub>

Voldemort wasn't himself a Death Eater so I think this errs on the side of him not having one. Why would he ever touch someone else's if he has his own? I don't think he'd need one either because he's usually with some cretin like Wormtail at least and if he's not he's doing private things that he wouldn't want to call others to anyway. Even if he did he could just apparate to a Death Eater and press the mark.

Comment: Oh, good point that Voldemort himself wasn't actually a Death Eater. Therefore, why would he have a Dark Mark? Good answer. :)

Answer (score 15):

It appears that Voldemort **does not have his own Dark Mark**. We see him using Wormtail's mark to summon the Death Eaters in *Goblet of Fire*:

> “Hold out your arm,” said Voldemort lazily.
>   “Oh Master . . . thank you, Master . . .”
>   He extended the bleeding stump, but Voldemort laughed again.
>   “The other arm, Wormtail.”
>   “Master, please . . . please . . .”
>   Voldemort bent down and pulled out Wormtail’s left arm; he
>   forced the sleeve of Wormtail’s robes up past his elbow, and Harry
>   saw something upon the skin there, something like a vivid red tattoo
>   — a skull with a snake protruding from its mouth — the image
>   that had appeared in the sky at the Quidditch World Cup: the
>   Dark Mark. Voldemort examined it carefully, ignoring Wormtail’s
>   uncontrollable weeping.
>   “It is back,” he said softly, “they will all have noticed it . . . and
>   now, we shall see . . . now we shall know . . .”
>   He pressed his long white forefinger to the brand on Wormtail’s
>   arm.
>   The scar on Harry’s forehead seared with a sharp pain again, and
>   Wormtail let out a fresh howl; Voldemort removed his fingers from
>   Wormtail’s mark, and Harry saw that it had turned jet black.
> <sup>*-Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter Thirty-Three (The Death Eaters).*</sup>

Answer (score 8):

The Dark Mark was a way of marking his followers, the elite band.  He would not have required one as he was the boss.  The Dark Mark was there as a constant reminder to them of who their allegiance was supposed to lie with and another way of exerting control.  It was also something that those who wanted to climb the ladder would have been desperate to have and it would have spurred them on to do ever more despicable deeds to achieve recognition and favour.

Comment: How would you say he summoned his Death Eaters when he was alone? When Bellatrix summoned him when the trio was at Malfoy Manor, how was he alerted? When one of the Carrows caught Harry in Ravenclaw Tower, Snape knew immediately, and when he clutched his left forearm, McGonagall said (paraphrase), "That's right -- you Death Eaters have your own private means of communication," referring to the Dark Mark. I don't know for sure about Voldemort, hence the question, but these are all factors that can't be ignored and have to be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth pointing out that in Deathly Hallows, Bellatrix and Malfoy have a tussle over which one of them will touch THEIR mark to summon Voldemort. So I would think that yes, he would have to have a dark mark, or at least the ability to feel it when one is pressed, for him to recognize when one of the OTHER death eaters is trying to summon him.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the incident with Wormtail in *Goblet of Fire* is necessarily evidence that Voldemort himself did not have a mark. Voldemort may have simply been checking if his rebirth had caused the mark to fully return. Here is the description with my emphasis:

> Voldemort bent down and pulled out Wormtail’s left arm; he forced the sleeve of Wormtail’s robes up past his elbow, and Harry saw something upon the skin there, something like a vivid red tattoo — a skull with a snake protruding from its mouth — the image that had appeared in the sky at the Quidditch World Cup: the Dark Mark. **Voldemort examined it carefully, ignoring Wormtail’s uncontrollable weeping.**
>
> **“It is back,” he said softly, "they will all have noticed it... and now, we shall see... now we shall know..."**
>
> He pressed his long white forefinger to the brand on Wormtail’s arm.

Once Voldemort confirmed that the mark had returned he might simply not have bothered to touch his own mark if he was already holding Wormtail's arm and could just touch Wormtail's.

That said, Snape's description of the Dark Mark at the end of *Goblet of Fire* does seem to indicate that Voldemort does not have his own mark (my emphasis):

> When he touched the mark **of any Death Eater**, we were to Disapparate, and Apparate, instantly, at his side.

However, even if Voldemort doesn't have an actual Dark Mark on his body, he is still somehow connected to the "Dark Mark Network", as we know from *Deathly Hallows* that he feels when Death Eaters press their marks (my emphasis):

> He was Voldemort, and the skeletal wizard in front before him was laughing toothlessly at him; he was enraged at **the summons he felt** — he had warned them, he had told them to summon him for nothing less than Potter.